# How do I manage to surface-mount an electrical box on vinyl siding?

Tags: electrical, vinyl-siding

I am looking to install an outdoor receptacle on vinyl siding. My house has a basement and the vinyl siding on the outside covers the rim joist that is on top of the basement foundation wall. I figure I can just drill through the rim joist and siding, say with a 1/2" or 3/4" spade bit and surface-mount an electrical box on a vinyl siding block.

Would that create an adequate installation, or do I need to get more involved with cutting the siding and installing the electrical box in a siding j-block?

I would of course use screws long enough to secure the electrical box and siding block to the rim joist and use a weatherproof box, receptacle, and in-use weatherproof cover. The rim joist is 18-24 inches above grade, so surface water and snow buildup wouldn't be a concern.

Comment: I have seen them mounted on the outside of the vinyl and I think this looks less than professional on top of sticking out at least an inch further than if the siding is cut. There are trim pieces that will fit around a small cut out like this so it will look professional, the bell box won’t protrude as far and it can be solidly anchored. So cutting the siding is my preference when installing a receptacle in vinyl or aluminum siding.